# Does $\int_a^bf^p=0$ imply $\int_a^bf=0$?

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration

Let $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ be a nonnegative Riemann integrable function. If $\int_a^bf^p=0$ for some $p>0$, is it true that $\int_a^bf=0$ ? It is obviously true if $p=1$, and the Hölder's inequality
$$\left|\int_a^bfg\right|\leq\left(\int_a^b|f|^p\right)^{1/p}\left(\int_a^b|g|^p\right)^{1/p}$$
implies that it is true if $p>1$. But what if $0<p<1$ ?
I would prefer a solution which does not use Lebesgue integral or measure zero sets if possible, please.

Comment: Let $[a,b]=[-1,+1]$ and $f(x)=x^2$, what happen when $p=\frac{3}{2}$?

Comment: @The_lost $f^{3/2}$ would be $|x|^3$, which doesn't integrate to zero.

Comment: Let $\epsilon > 0$. You can bound $f^p$ above by a step function $s$ whose integral is less than $\epsilon^p$. Then $f$ is bounded above by the step function $s^{1/p}$, whose integral is less than $\epsilon$. Basically we're just using monotonicity of $x \mapsto x^p$ for nonnegative $x$ and $p$.

Comment: @Bungo, Thank you, It was tricky!, should I remove the comment?

Comment: @The_lost I suggest leaving the comment as is. It looks like a valid counterexample at first glance. It fooled me for a moment. :-)

Comment: If $f$ is nonnegative, that means that $f^p$ is also nonnegative. If $\int_{a}^{b}f^p = 0$, then $f^p = 0 \rightarrow f = 0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $ 0<p<1$. Let $M=\sup \{f(x): a \leq x \leq b\}$. Let $g=\frac f M$. Then $\int g^{p}=0$ and $0\leq g \leq 1$. Hence $0 \leq g \leq g^{p}$ which gives  $0\leq \int g \leq \int g^{p}=0$ which gives $\int g=0$. This implies $\int f=0$.

Comment: Nice solution. But I don't understand why you don't just use that if $f$ is non-negative, then so is $f^p$, and if $\int f^p = 0$ we must have $f^p = 0$ (a.e.) and hence $f = 0$ (a.e.), so $\int f = 0$. Am I (and @automaticallyGenerated) missing something?

Comment: I think OP wants a proof without using measure theory. This is supposed to be a question on Riemann integration. @md2perpe

Answer (score 1):

First of all, let sign $\ =\ $ mean "almost equal" above.

The Answer is YES.

Otherwise, if integral $\ \int\ $ on the right were positive, there would exist $\ s>0\ $ such that the measure

$$ m\ :=\ \mu(f^{-1}((s;\infty))\ >\ 0 $$

would be indeed positive. Then

$$ \int_a^b f^p\ \ge\ s^p\cdot m\ >\ 0 $$

-- a contradiction which proves "YES".

Answer (score 1):

Here, we show the contrapositive: if $\int_E|f(x)|\,\mathrm{d}x\gt0$, then $\int_E|f(x)|^p\,\mathrm{d}x\gt0$.

---

Using the formula
$$
\int_E|f(x)|^p\,\mathrm{d}x=\int_0^\infty\mu\{x\in E:|f(x)|\gt\lambda\}\,p\lambda^{p-1}\,\mathrm{d}\lambda\tag1
$$
if $\int_E|f(x)|\,\mathrm{d}x\gt0$, then
$$
\int_0^\infty\mu\{x\in E:|f(x)|\gt\lambda\}\,\mathrm{d}\lambda\gt0\tag2
$$
and so there must be some $\lambda_0\gt0$ so that $\mu\{x\in E:|f(x)|\gt\lambda_0\}\gt0$. Consequently, since $\mu\{x\in E:|f(x)|\gt\lambda\}$ is a non-increasing function of $\lambda$,
$$
\begin{align}
\int_E|f(x)|^p\,\mathrm{d}x
&\ge\int_0^{\lambda_0}\mu\{x\in E:|f(x)|\gt\lambda_0\}\,p\lambda^{p-1}\,\mathrm{d}\lambda\\[6pt]
&=\mu\{x\in E:|f(x)|\gt\lambda_0\}\,\lambda_0^p\\[9pt]
&\gt0\tag3
\end{align}
$$